# rxjs: Subscriber does not fire on all changes in different class

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a js class that has a BehaviorSubject and an Observable. I want to subsribe to the Observable in a different class, which does not work, properly.

```
//class One: 
export default ClassOne {
     constructor(){
         this._store = new BehaviorSubject({}); 
         this.store = this._store.asObservable(); 
         this.store.subscribe(data => {console.log(data)}) //logs the data, no Problem here
         //{};{ test: { foo: "bar", max: "muster" } };{ test: { foo: "bar", max: "muster" } };...
     }
     addData(data){ this._store.next(data)} //iscalled a few times.

     getStore () {return this.store}        //using a getter Function does not work either

}

//class Two
import class1 from "./class1"; 
ClassTwo {
    constructor(){
        this.one = new ClassOne(); 
        this.one.store.subscribe(data =>{console.log(data)}) //only logs {} once. Is never fired again. 
        this.one.getStore().subscribe(data =>{console.log(data)}) //Same Problem
    }
}
```

**So My main questions: How can I make sure that the subscriber gets all the changes in ClassTwo?**

Note that the Observable is defined and fires once, but is not notified with new changes.

Does it make a difference when ClassOne is a Singleton?:

```
  //class One: 
instance = null; 
export default ClassOne {
     constructor(){
         if (instance === null) {
             instance = this;
         }
         instance._store = new BehaviorSubject({}); 
         instance.store = this._store.asObservable(); 
         instance.store.subscribe(data => {console.log(data)}) //logs the data, no Problem here
     }
     addData(data){ instance._store.next(data)} //iscalled a few times. 
     getStore () {return instance.store}        //using a getter Function does not work either
}
```

**Edit: Test if its a singleton**
(using jest)

```
beforeAll(() => {
   one = new ClassOne();
});
test("Singleton Test", () => {
  let one2 = new ClassOne();
  expect(one2 instanceof ClassOne).toEqual(true);
  expect(one2).toEqual(one);
  expect(one2 === one).toEqual(true);
});
```

**Edit2: Use of Add data**

```
beforeAll(() => {

one = new ClassOne();
two = new ClassTwo(); 
});
  test("", (done) => {
    one.addData({ test: { foo: "bar", max: "muster" } });
    one.addData({ test: { foo: "bar", max: "muster" } });
    one.addData({ test: { foo: "bar", max: "muster" } });        

    //I just coded this by heart, but the test is somthing like this
    expect(one.getStore()).toEqual(two.one.store);

    //makes sure that the subscriber have enough time
    setTimeout(() => done(), 5000);
  }, 6000);
```

**Edit3: Using share/shareReplay**

I have changed the getStore() function:

```
//ClassOne
getStore(){ return instance.store.pipe(share()) }
//and I tried: 
getStore(){ return instance.store.pipe(shareReplay()) }

//ClassTwo: 
this.one.getStore().subscribe(data =>{console.log(data)})
```

But the Problem remains.

**Edit4: Some Trouble shooting**

So after some testing and reading I come to the conclusion that subscriptions in constructors are not working properly.

While this is not working:

```
   let two = new ClassTwo(); //with the subscription on the store
```

This works:

```
   let two = new ClassTwo(); //without the subscription on the store
   two.subscribeToMyStore(); 

   //subscribeToMyStore: 
   subscribeToMyStore(){
       this.one.store.subscribe(data =>{console.log(data)})
   }
```

So why cant I do subscriptions in the constructor?

And why would it subscribe in the constructor of ClassOne but not ClassTwo?

Comment: It works as expected by me. "this.one.store.subscribe(data =>{console.log(data)}) //only logs {} once. Is never fired again." This is correct, since you use BehaviorSubject. 
As soon as you call addData of instanceOfClassTwo.one, then it logs new value twice.

Comment: Btw if you use Angular, then code from ClassOne seems like a candidate to be a service.

Comment: Im not using angular. Im creating a npm package with classes similar to the described ones.

Comment: Do you want to share same instance of ClassOne between different objects?

Comment: yes, I do. Its supposed to be some kind of store.

Comment: @matvs The initial console.logs are not the problem. The problem is that is I execute addData() then ClassOne is logging the changes, but ClassTwo not. The initial logs work as intended.

Comment: Please provide snippet how you call addData().

Comment: @matvs Done. Its a jest test. Im still struggeling testing a subsriber properly, but the current problem is that the subscriber in classTwo is not getting the changes, which I checked through the console.logs().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the Problem was the speed of Jest. Jest finished and cleaned up everything before the logs in the subscription of classTwo were executed.

Although wierd, the workaround that worked for me was to fire the complete event in my test and only call done() in the callback of complete. Looks like this:

```
 beforeAll(() => {
    one = new ClassOne();
    two = new ClassTwo(); //subcription in constructor
 });
 test("", (done) => {
    one.addData({ test: { foo: "bar", max: "muster" } });
    one.addData({ test: { foo: "bar", max: "muster" } });
    one.addData({ test: { foo: "bar", max: "muster" } });        

    //I just coded this by heart, but the test is something like this
    two.one.store.subscribe({
        complete() {
            //Test the final state of everything here
            //Only call done() here. 
            done();
        },
    });
    setTimeout(
        () => one.store.complete(),   //call complete after a timeout
        1000
    );
 }, 2000);
```

So my takeaway here:

- Subscribing in constructors works.
- Make sure that the test environment dont destroy the underlying Instance of the Obeservable before they received changes.
- Call complete on the (Behavior)Subject in a setTimeOut and call done() in the callback of complete().
- Why the subscription in classTwo is that slow that the data is only received in classOne is still beyond me.

Answer (score 3):

You have to reuse **the same** instance. Either ensure it is singleton and inject in through the constructor using some DI framework, or export singleton yourself from separate moudle and don't forget to [share](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share) it. Note that there exist quite popular scenarios when [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) is needed.

Comment: I have added a jest test (rewritten for the question) to show that it is a singleton. So the instance should be the same.

Comment: Also the subscriber in ClassOne is only there for testing purposes. My initial problem was that the subscriber in ClassTwo is not getting the changes.

Comment: So by sharing you mean somehting like this?: getStore () {return this.store.pipe(share())} Anyways thanks for the tipp with share. I will check them out, but need some time to apply them in my actuall project.

Comment: So I have tried it out but it does not work. It was still usefull, as I plan to apply multiple subscribers. Will extend the code in the question soon.

Comment: I am not sure how tests resolve signletons and do they preserve the same memory or create new instances; but it will work for sure in regular runtime, tested many many times. Check Angular docs for more advanced examples of DI with RXJS.